# Ormlite mapping fields to a simple member class

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I'm experimenting with ORMLite for android.

I have a pre built SQLite db that i am loading on the android device. I have stored position information as LocationX, LocationY columns:

```
CREATE TABLE graphicsinstances(Name STRING , LocationX FLOAT , LocationY FLOAT , SizeX FLOAT , SizeY FLOAT );
```

Catch is, at runtime i'd like this to look something like:

```
public class Vector2
{
    public float X;
    public float Y;
}
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "graphicsinstances")
public class graphicsinstance
{
    public GraphicalEntityInstance()
    {
        mName               = null;
        mPosition           = Vector2.zero();
        mSize               = Vector2.zero();
    }
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "Name", canBeNull = false)
    public String mName;

    //Olympic standard optimism
    //@DatabaseField(columnName = "Location", canBeNull = false)
    //public Vector2 mPosition;

    // current (unsatisfactory) method:
    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, useGetSet=true)
    private float LocationX;
    public float getLocationX() { return mPosition.X;}
    public void setLocationX(float x) { mPosition.X = x;}
    // repeat for Y, SizeX & SizeY!
}
```

Have I missed something obvious or am I completely barking up the wrong tree? can anyone suggest an alternative/prettier  method?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Are you having problems with this?  Does not not compile or run?  What errors are you getting?

Comment: Sorry, i want to map the data within the LocationX & LocationY columns to the X & Y fields of the mPosition instance. My workaround using the getset mechanism works, but it introduces an unused member variable and looks nasty enough to make me think im going about it in completely the wrong way :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand, you want to map a table into a class with sub-classes.  In your example I guess you want to load the `LocationX` and `LocationY` fields into the `mposition` which I guess is a `Vector2`?

I think it is ok to have a `getMPosition()` and `setMPosition(mpos)` methods that do the mapping between the `LocationX` and `LocationY` fields but you are not going to be able to do that mapping auto-magically with ORMLite.

---

From a purity standpoint I always recommend using what database circles call an "entity class".  This class mirrors your database structure exactly.  It should have a one-to-one correspondence between fields in the table and the class.  It can have methods like `hashCode()`, `equals()`, and the standard getter/setters but very little else.

You could create a wrapping object that takes a `GraphicsInstance` object in its constructor and does the `Vector2` mapping and allows the other operations.  When you are ready to persist it when you would need to go back to the `GraphicsInstance` object.

Comment: Yeah, that definitely sounds like a better solution. I'll try that out ;)

Thank you for your speedy replies!